# Pushwoosh - Not registering device on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, pushwoosh

I have created a Cordova-based hybrid app for iOS and Android. I added Pushwoosh library, but push notifications are not working as the device is not being registered.
Checking Android Pushwoosh boot log (which is working), user registration is done first, and if that is correct, it goes for the device registration. On iOS, I get this log (AppId, userId and hwid have been hidden):

x
   |    Pushwoosh request:
   | Url:      https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/registerUser
   | Payload:  {"request":{"device_type":1,"application":"XXXXX","userId":"XXXXX","v":"3.1.1.434","hwid":"XXXXX"}}
   | Status:   "200 no error"
   | Response: {"status_code": 200, "status_message": "OK","response":"Request format is not valid."}
   x

As I understand, the problem with the User registration ("Request format is not valid.") is avoiding the device registration to be launched.
Is that correct? What could the problem be with the user registration?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to look for /registerUser. This API is for user-centric push notifications and might be disabled on the account.

You need to look for /registerDevice. You'll see this in the logs once you subscribe for push notifications.